# do notation for Either and Maybe monads

Tags: haskell

There is a method:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Network.HTTP.Types

getJSON :: String -> IO (Either String Value)
getJSON url = eitherDecode <$> simpleHttp url
```

And instead of this:

```
method1 :: String -> IO Object
method1 url = do
                maybeJson <- getJSON url
                case maybeJson of
                   jsonValue -> 
                    case jsonValue of
                      Object jsonObject -> return jsonObject
                      _ -> error "error123"
                  Left errorMsg -> error $ "error456"
```

I can do this:

```
method1 :: String -> IO Object
method1 url = do
                Right jsonValue <- getJSON url
                case jsonValue of
                  Object jsonObject -> return jsonObject
                  _ -> error "error123"
```

Is there any way to simplify it even more without using any libraries like lens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't care about the particular error messages, you could merge the patterns further:

```
method1 url = do
                Right (Object jsonObject) <- getJSON url
                return jsonObject
```

Comment: is there any way to do something like `method1 url = getJSON url >>= return ???` ?

Comment: this seems to work `method1 url = getJSON url >>= \(Right (Object jsonObject)) -> return jsonObject
`

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Yeah I considered writing that instead (the `do` version is mostly just syntactic sugar for it), but figured the difference was small.